# What class should I run async calls from?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

In my iOS app I have a view controller and a UITableView subclass on one of my views. Currently the UITableView manages it's own data (creating connections, and being the delegate which handles the callbacks).

I was wondering if this is best practice? Is it better to run this on the view controller and then pass the data into the table? Does this not matter at all?

Please explain the reasons in addition to answering my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would be more standard to implement the `delegate` and `dataSource` methods in the `ViewController`.

It is quite unusual to subclass the `UI*View` classes, except to customise drawing. `UITableViewCell` is a bit of an exception to this rule.

If you find your `ViewController` getting a bit big you might think about implementing the delegate and dataSource in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mcfedr's answer, views are things that interact with user and it is generally good to separate concepts (unless unavoidable). Also note that historic versions of ios (iirc) view controllers may load/unload views on demand, so any application logic in there may cease to exist.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I generally have only one class... The UIViewController instance that contains the following view hierarchy:

- view -> myTableView

With this approach, my UIViewController will:

- Have an IBOutlet to a UITableView (myTableView)
- Implement methods of UITableViewDelegate
- Implement methods of UITableViewDatasource
- Set myTableVIew.delegate to self
- Set myTableView.datasource to self

When the host UIViewController is the delegate and datasource of your UIViewContoller, all code can exist in one class.  This keeps the code of your project tighter but does tightly couple your logic.

The alternative approach would be to subclass UITableView and implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource.  This will be a desirable approach if:

- You wanted to reuse the UITableView in multiple UIViewController
- You wanted to encapsulate the UITableView logic from the UIViewController

Here is the thought process I use:

- Am I going to reuse this UITableView and its logic?

  - Yes -> UIViewController class and UITableView subclass
  - No ->  UIViewController class only

The best practice would depend on the number of programmers involved, the repeatability of the UITableView, coding patterns already established.  This is often a matter of preference and I hope my answer shed some light on why you would go either way,

Comment: The reason I've been doing this on separate classes is because on some pages I have two tableviews next to each other and the delegate calls need to be different.

Comment: That would be another reason to subclass UITableView.  You could make a UIViewController the delegate/datasource of multiple UITableViews but each method would have to perform conditional logic and more importantly, you would be forced to implement the same methods in both which could lead undesirable results.  For your purposes, I think you have chosen the best practice.